# Вывести все индексы минимальных элементов. Java

Tags: java

Есть массив mas = -1, 22, 33, 44, 567, 567, 44, 33, 22, -1.

Необходимо вывести индексы минимальных элементов в убывающем порядке.

В моем случае это 9 0.

Смог найти только один минимальный индекс.

```
 static void step3(int[] mas) {
        int indexOfMin = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < mas.length; i++) {
            if (mas[i] < mas[indexOfMin]) {
                indexOfMin = i;
            }
        }
            System.out.println("Индекс минимального элемента: " + indexOfMin);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 static void step3(int[] arr) {
        int indexOfMin = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
// немного поменял алгоритм поиска минимального элемента,
            //но я думаю разберётесь

            if (arr[indexOfMin] > arr[i]) {
                indexOfMin = i;
            }
        }
        //создаём строку, можно изменить на стрингБилдер

        String moreElements = "";

// сравниваем наш минимальный элемент со следующим элементом массива,
// и при совпадении конкатенируем индекс со строкой
    
        for (int i = indexOfMin; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[indexOfMin] == arr[i]) {
                moreElements += " " + i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Индекс минимального элемента: " + moreElements);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

На первом проходе определяется *последний* индекс минимального элемента, используя нестрогое сравнение `<=` с текущим минимумом, а потом на обратном проходе выводятся индексы минимумов.
Также имеет смысл обозначить начальное значение индекса минимума -1 для случая пустого массива.

```
static void printMinIndexes(int ... mas) {
    int indexOfMin = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
        if (indexOfMin < 0 || mas[i] <= mas[indexOfMin]) {
            indexOfMin = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Min indexes: ");
    if (indexOfMin == -1) {
        System.out.print("not found");
    } else for (int i = indexOfMin; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (mas[i] == mas[indexOfMin]) {
            System.out.print(i + "  ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Тесты:

```
printMinIndexes(); // Min indexes: not found

printMinIndexes(-1, 22, 33, 44, 567, 567, 44, 33, 22, -1); // Min indexes: 9  0
```

---

Также можно отслеживать первый индекс минимума, чтобы использовать его при выводе минимумов как ограничитель (если первый минимум находится не в самом начале входного массива):

```java
static void printMinIndexes(int ... mas) {
    int firstMin = -1;
    int lastMin = -1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
        if (firstMin < 0 || mas[i] < mas[firstMin]) {
            firstMin = lastMin = i;
        } else if (mas[i] == mas[lastMin]) {
            lastMin = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Min indexes ");
    if (firstMin == -1) {
        System.out.print("not found");
    } else {
        System.out.print("between " + firstMin + " and " + lastMin + ": ");
        for (int i = lastMin; i >= firstMin; i--) {
            if (mas[i] == mas[firstMin]) {
                System.out.print(i + "  ");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Тесты:

```
printMinIndexes();
printMinIndexes(3, 2);
printMinIndexes( 22, 33, 44, 2, 567, 2, 567, 2, 44, 33, 22);
printMinIndexes( -1, 22, 33, 44, 567, 567, 44, 33, 22, -1);
```

Результаты:

```
Min indexes not found
Min indexes between 1 and 1: 1  
Min indexes between 3 and 7: 7  5  3  
Min indexes between 0 and 9: 9  0
```